# Cross Compiling ARM7 code from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, arm, cross-compiling

Is it possible to compile for ARM7 from visual studio (2008/2010) express or professional? If so, can I be directed as to how to do so? I've read from other posts about the Yagarto toolchain. How does it all fit into the picture?

I'm very green in this field (c# programmer) so any guidance will be very much appreciated. The last IDE I used to compile my test application was CodeWarrior. I write the code in VS and compile from CodeWarrior. Not sure of debug support but that is another topic. At the moment, I want to be able to write and compile from VS.

Thank you.

Comment: I looked at this the other day. If you know enough about MSBuild, look at the .NET Micro Framework's Porting Kit. I am too stupid to follow, so I just stick to Eclipse for now.

Comment: I really know very little about MSBuild. The only thing I've every added is a copy task to copy some files around.
Did you get ARM7 to work with Eclipse? I followed the Yagarto tutorial and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Yagarto just provides gcc compiled for win32, it does not have any integration with VS (but does work with Eclipse IDE).

Compiling from VS is possible, but not trivial. You have several options (note, I have not tested any of them myself, I usually stick to "make" from command line).

1. "Makefile project". It is one of the options available when creating a new project in VS. Many simple projects can be compiled with a single command line, and you can use this type of project for that.
2. use MSBuild (available in VS2010). Someone made [a helper](http://hobbit-hole.org/hg/hgwebdir.cgi/gccbuild/raw-file/9b090f0421ad/ReadMe.rst) to build GCC projects in MSBuild. I don't know if it will work with Yagarto.
3. there is a complete(?) commercial solution called [WinGDB](http://www.wingdb.com/). They provide not only compilation but  also debugging from inside VS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I really know nothing about compiling with make nor do I know which compiler, linker etc to call. WinGDB seems promising. Can you guide me in the direction to go. I tried the Yagarto with Eclipse and it didn't work.