# How to create c/c++ library in Window , and use in iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, c++, c, windows

I want to use c or c++ code to build an library that can use in iPhone .

I had asked a similar question ["make arm architecture c library in mac"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593113/make-arm-architecture-c-library-in-mac)  .

And someone says use Xcode to build static library .

But I must build the library in Windows  (maybe use Visual Studio) .

And it seems will have architecture problem

In fact , I dont quite understand how to create the library in Windows   , and how to let the library use in iPhone project ? .

Can someone tell me some tips?  Some gcc commands like :

`gcc -c math.c -o math.o

ar rcs libmath.a math.o`

(But I use this command to make libmath.a in Linux , and take it to iPhone , it says the lib has no architecture info and cannot use )

or some visual studio steps?

Comment: Why must you build the library in Windows? VS has some cross compiler support, but only for Windows devices that it knows about. I'd be quite surprised if you could build for the iPhone in VS because the iPhone doesn't run Windows CE. Thankfully.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644286/cross-compiling-arm7-code-from-visual-studio (your first obstackle is to get a compiler running on windows that produces arm code)

Answer (score 0):

If you will use POSIX-only environment in your library, you will be able to use it in Windows and on iPhone as well (but, probably, with some #define's)